# FTS - optimized pg_search not using dictionary in searching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, full-text-search, pg-search

I got problem with my search functionality in Rails application. I'm using pg_search with Postgresql and loaded polish dictionary into it. I did #343 RailsCasts tutorial and everything is fine when I use default `search()` method (horribly slow performance), but when optimized by suggested in tutorial SQL query it doesn't work as it should - not throwing any errors, just not using dictionary. For instance, by phrase "herbata owoc" it finds all quite proper records, although not the same as default "search" method, but by proper phrase which is "herbata owocowa" it doesn't find anything, when "search" method returns accurate records.

Of course I did migration which add the indexes. Also I tried solutions with some triggers etc. (http://railscasts.com/episodes/343-full-text-search-in-postgresql?view=comments), but it didn't help. I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.0.5, PostgreSQL 9.1.13, pg_Search 0.7.6.

Method call in controller:

```
Product.text_search(params[:query])
```

Model "Product":

```
include PgSearch

pg_search_scope :text_search, against: [:title, :description],
              using: {tsearch: {dictionary: "polish"}}

def self.text_search(query)
  if query.present?
    # search(query)
    rank = <<-RANK
      ts_rank(to_tsvector(products.title), plainto_tsquery(#{sanitize(query)})) + ts_rank(to_tsvector(products.description), plainto_tsquery(#{sanitize(query)}))
    RANK
    where("to_tsvector('polish', products.title) @@ :q or to_tsvector('polish', products.description) @@ :q", q: query.split(" ").join(" & ")).order("#{rank} DESC")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

Migration:

```
class AddSearchIndexToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "create index products_title on products using gin(to_tsvector('polish', title))"
    execute "create index products_description on products using gin(to_tsvector('polish', description))"
  end

  def down
    execute "drop index products_title"
    execute "drop index products_description"
  end
end
```

My query which gives no results:

```
Product Load (1.2ms)
SELECT "products".* 
FROM "products" 
INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "products"."category_id" 
WHERE 
    "products"."active" = 't' 
    AND "categories"."active" = 't' 
    AND (to_tsvector('polish', products.title) @@ 'herbata & owocowa' 
        OR to_tsvector('polish', products.description) @@ 'herbata & owocowa') 
        AND (1=1) 
ORDER BY 
    title, 
    ts_rank(to_tsvector(products.title), plainto_tsquery('herbata owocowa')) 
    + ts_rank(to_tsvector(products.description), plainto_tsquery('herbata owocowa'))
    DESC
```

`search()` query which gives expected results, but very slowly:

```
Product Load (15391.1ms)  
SELECT "products".*, ((ts_rank((to_tsvector('polish', coalesce("products"."title"::text, '')) || to_tsvector('polish', coalesce("products"."description"::text, ''))), (to_tsquery('polish', ''' ' || 'herbata' || ' ''') && to_tsquery('polish', ''' ' || 'owocowa' || ' ''')), 0))) AS pg_search_rank 
FROM "products" 
INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "products"."category_id" 
WHERE 
    "products"."active" = 't' 
    AND "categories"."active" = 't' 
    AND (
        ((to_tsvector('polish', coalesce("products"."title"::text, '')) || to_tsvector('polish', coalesce("products"."description"::text, ''))) 
        @@ (to_tsquery('polish', ''' ' || 'herbata' || ' ''') 
            && to_tsquery('polish', ''' ' || 'owocowa' || ' ''')))
    ) 
    AND (1=1) 
ORDER BY 
    title, pg_search_rank DESC, "products"."id" ASC
```

I tried to write similar Select like `search()` gives, but I have failed.

Example data:

(1 case)

- default search() method, phrase: "herbata owocowa", expected first 5 results:

  ```
  [[0] #<Product:0x000000083fa3d8> {
               :title => "BIOFIX Herbata Kompozycja Owocowa 60 szt",
         :description => "Propozycja od dobrze znanej i cenionej polskiej marki Biofix. Doskonała herbata owocowa, która zadowoli wszystkich miłośników bogatego smaku. Idealna propozycja na każdą porę dnia. Doskonale smakuje z miodem lub dodatkiem plastrów cytryny. Zapraszamy do zapoznania się z produktami z pozostałych kategorii. Zrób już dzisiaj zakupy przez internet, a nasze delikatesy chętnie dostarczą Ci smaczną paczkę."
  },
  [1] #<Product:0x000000083fa040> {
               :title => "BIOFIX Herbata Premium Hawaii Dream 20 szt",
         :description => "Propozycja od dobrze znanej i cenionej polskiej marki Biofix. Doskonała herbata owocowa, która zadowoli wszystkich miłośników bogatego smaku. Idealna propozycja na każdą porę dnia. Doskonale smakuje z miodem lub dodatkiem plastrów cytryny. Zapraszamy do zapoznania się z produktami z pozostałych kategorii. Zrób już dzisiaj zakupy przez internet, a nasze delikatesy chętnie dostarczą Ci smaczną paczkę."
  },
  [2] #<Product:0x000000083f9c80> {
               :title => "BOBOVITA Herbata dla dzieci cytrynowa 200 g",
         :description => "Herbatka owocowa Bobovita to łagodny napój dla niemowląt. Ma delikatny aromat i przyjemny smak, dzięki czemu jej picie jest prawdziwą przyjemnością. W chłodne dni przynosi uczucie ukojenia, a podana na zimno odświeża i orzeźwia. Nie zawiera substancji konserwujących i barwników. Produkt przeznaczony dla dzieci po 9 miesiącu życia. Nasz supermarket online to dobre rozwiązanie dla każdego."
  },
  [3] #<Product:0x000000083f9898> {
               :title => "BOBOVITA Herbata dla dzieci malinowa z dziką różą 200 g",
         :description => "Herbatka owocowa Bobovita to łagodny napój dla niemowląt. Ma delikatny aromat i przyjemny smak, dzięki czemu jej picie jest prawdziwą przyjemnością. W chłodne dni przynosi uczucie ukojenia, a podana na zimno odświeża i orzeźwia. Nie zawiera substancji konserwujących i barwników. Produkt przeznaczony dla dzieci po 5 miesiącu życia. Nasz supermarket online to dobre rozwiązanie dla każdego."
  },
  [4] #<Product:0x000000083f9460> {
               :title => "BOBOVITA Herbata dla dzieci malinowa z dziką różą 400 g",
         :description => "Herbatka owocowa Bobovita to łagodny napój dla niemowląt. Ma delikatny aromat i przyjemny smak, dzięki czemu jej picie jest prawdziwą przyjemnością. W chłodne dni przynosi uczucie ukojenia, a podana na zimno odświeża i orzeźwia. Nie zawiera substancji konserwujących i barwników. Produkt przeznaczony dla dzieci po 5 miesiącu życia. Zamów już teraz szybka dostawa do domu gwarantowana."
  }]
  ```
- customized query gives nil, phrase: "herbata owocowa"

---

(2 case)

- both default search() method and customized method gives the same results, phrase: "herbata owoc", first 5 results:

  ```
  [[0] #<Product:0x00000009f53120> {
               :title => "ANIA Ciasteczka orkiszowe z goją 120 g",
         :description => "Wyjątkowo zdrowe, chrupiące orkiszowe ciasteczka z owocem Goji. Wypieczone z najlepszej jakości naturalnych składników. Stanowią idealny dodatek do filiżanki ciepłej kawy lub herbaty. Dostępne w szerokiej gamie smakowej. Zapraszamy do zapoznania się z produktami z pozostałych kategorii.  Złóż już dzisiaj zamówienie w naszych delikatesach online, gwarantujemy szybką dostawę.\r\n",
  },
  [1] #<Product:0x0000000a02df00> {
               :title => "BIOFIX Herbata  Premium Aronia z Acai 20 szt",
         :description => "Propozycja od dobrze znanej i cenionej polskiej marki Biofix. Doskonała herbata z owoców aronii, która zadowoli wszystkich miłośników bogatego smaku. Idealna propozycja na każdą porę dnia. Doskonale smakuje z miodem lub dodatkiem plastrów cytryny. Zapraszamy do zapoznania się z produktami z pozostałych kategorii. Zrób już dzisiaj zakupy przez internet, a nasze delikatesy chętnie dostarczą Ci smaczną paczkę.",
  },
  [2] #<Product:0x0000000a02db90> {
               :title => "BOBOVITA Herbata dla dzieci z owoców południowych 200 g",
         :description => "Herbatka owocowa Bobovita to łagodny napój dla niemowląt. Ma delikatny aromat i przyjemny smak, dzięki czemu jej picie jest prawdziwą przyjemnością. W chłodne dni przynosi uczucie ukojenia, a podana na zimno odświeża i orzeźwia. Nie zawiera substancji konserwujących i barwników. Produkt przeznaczony dla dzieci po 5 miesiącu życia. Nasz supermarket online to dobre rozwiązanie dla każdego.",
  },
  [3] #<Product:0x0000000a02d820> {
               :title => "BONNE MAMAN Dżem z figi 370 g",
         :description => "Dżem przygotowywany według tradycyjnej francuskiej receptury, której korzenie sięgają XVI wieku. Doskonałe proporcje składników i duża zawartość owoców figi wpływają na unikalny smak i aromat tego dżemu. Znakomity do deserów, naleśników, omletów. Może stanowić zdrową alternatywę dla cukru i osłodzić niejedną herbatę. Supermarket internetowy czeka by dostarczyć Ci tę owocową słodycz zamkniętą w słoiczku.",
  },
  [4] #<Product:0x0000000a02d4b0> {
               :title => "BONNE MAMAN Dżem z krojonej pigwy 370 g",
         :description => "Dżem przygotowywany według tradycyjnej francuskiej receptury, której korzenie sięgają XVI wieku. Doskonałe proporcje składników, w tym duża zawartość najstaranniej dobranych owoców pigwy wpływają na oryginalny i niepowtarzalny smak i konsystencję dżemu. Świetnie nadaje się do deserów, ciast oraz herbaty. Supermarket internetowy z radością dostarczy Ci słoiczek od Bonne Maman!",
  }]
  ```

Comment: You've failed to provide the actual query this generates, any sample data, expected results and actual results. How do you expect anyone to be able help you?

Answer (score 1):

OK - I've reformatted the SQL to try and get a clearer view of what's going on.

Two points you need to bear in mind:

1. If you pick a dictionary ('polish') then you should use it *everywhere* otherwise some parts of the query will probably be using a different (default) dictionary. That is probably why you get no results in the first case.
2. If you want to use an index, then it needs to match what you are querying against. In the second query you are coalescing and concatenating a bunch of strings, so no index can be used.

However, in your second query you do seem to have specified the same dictionary throughout, which is why you get results.

If you make sure your first query specifies a polish dictionary throughout, there's a chance it would use the index.

You might want to have a single index over a single "document" with relevant weights for title and description too (see [the manuals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html))